# External Hard drive not functioning

Tags: boot, hard-drive

can anyone please help with this problem. I have two external hard drives one is recognised and functioning properly ( label HDD 2 ), the other is not ( label HDD 1 ). The problem began when I was moving several files from my hard disc to the external drive and a power cut occured. After the electricity was restored and my computer turned back on, the HHD 1 external hard drive was no longer functioning and is not found in the "disks" utility. If I try to boot Ubuntu with this external drive plugged in, Ubuntu will not boot. I did see a brief message during one boot which mentioned "device descriptor error", but it stayed on the screen very briefly and I could not write down the full message in time. I have not seen this message again since then. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the computer hangs on shut down if the HDD 1 is plugged in

Comment: The hard disk enclosure electronics may be broken.  The physical disk inside should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn

Comment: using the command  lsusb in terminal provides me with this informatio
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. ( HDD 2) functioning

( Bus 003 Device 012: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub ) problem HDD 1

Comment: Put the drive in another enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

A power outage indeed can, when it is happening on the wrong split-second where it is being written to, cause significant damage to the file system of the drive. There may be significant corruption of the file system to the extent that sometimes, reformatting is required. In the worst case, there could be damage to the electronic components of the drive.

‣ Check whether your drive is seen as a device:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

‣ If the drive does not appear, chances are there is hardware failure. As user Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen outlined, you may try mounting the drive itself into another enclosure. If the drive also does not respond at that point, it will need to be replaced.

‣ If the drive appears, see whether the partition(s) on it are listed or not.

‣ If not, then the partition table may be damaged. If no data recovery is needed, you will then need to try repartitioning the drive to bring it back to use (`parted` or with graphical tools such as Gparted or Disks). If you need to recover data, your best bet is to consult a data recovery service, although you could try to recover the partitions yourself using the `testdisk` tool.

‣ If the partition table is still intact, then check and repair the file system(s)

```
sudo fsck /dev/####
```

You can see the device name(s) of the partition(s) in the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. After this, the file system should be accessible again and should be coherent.

Comment: The symptoms are more consistent with broken enclosure electronics than a broken file system, as there is not any response from the drive.

Comment: Indeed, I should also mention this option specifically.